# How to get scaled UWP inkstroke points?

Tags: uwp, scale, inkcanvas

I have an `inkStroke` in the `inkcanvas`, and I use method `GetInkPoints` to get the points collection of the inkstroke, if the inkcanvas size is 100 * 100 and I want to map the inkstroke to a page to 200*200, then I need to scale the inkstroke, the scale factor is 2, if I directly use point x and y to multiply scale factor, the shape of inkstroke will distort sometimes(for example when the inkstrole is a circle), so does anyone know how to make transform to a inkstroke and get its points then?

New added: I find that the inkstroke is consists of several Bézier curves, so does anyone know how to scale Bézier curve? Maybe I can scale each Bézier curve in a stroke and generate a new inkstroke and get its points.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scaled the `InkStroke`, we do not need to get the points in the [`InkCanvas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inkcanvas). We can use [`InkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer) to get all ink strokes in the collection.

We can use `InkStroke.PointTransform` property to set an affine transformation matrix to apply to the each `InkStroke`. The [`Matrix3x2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix3x2?view=netframework-4.7) provide `CreateScale` to create a scale matrix from the given X and Y components.

For example:

```
var MyStrokes=  MyInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
foreach (var stroke in MyStrokes)
{
    stroke.PointTransform = Matrix3x2.CreateScale(2, 2);
}
```

Comment: Actually just directly multiply scale factor works, I just make some mistakes about my scale factor. Thank you for your answer.